# Why do signed negative integers start at the lowest value?

Tags: sign

I can't really explain this question in words alone (probably why I can't find an answer), so I'll try to give as much detail as I can. This isn't really a practical question, I'm just curious.

So let's say we have a signed 8bit int.

```
sign | bytes   | sign 0 | sign 1
?    | 0000000 | (+)0   | (-)128
?    | 1111111 | (+)127 | (-)1
```

I don't understand why this works this way, can someone explain? In my head, it makes more sense for the value to be the same and for the sign to just put a plus or minus in front, so to me it looks backwards.

Comment: That diagram doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Two's complement is used because it's largely equivalent to unsigned integers, there are a thousand duplicates of this question that explain how that equivalence works.

Comment: It makes sense to me, which is likely why I don't understand the implementation. This is the way I see it: The sign byte just adds a sign, so why would the value bytes mean something totally different?

Comment: Also I'm sick of people saying "duplicate question" every time I come to this site to ask a question. If I knew where to find all the answers, I wouldn't have asked in the first place. What's even the point of this website if this is all its users have to offer?

Comment: Fair enough, I'll explain it again, if it doesn't get closed too soon.

Comment: @fay - please note that `duplicate question` isn't *necessarily* a criticism. You may not know the right words to search on, but there may already be a good explanation that somebody has already provided. Questions marked as duplicates are (usually) **kept**, and part of the purpose in doing that is to act as a sign-post for future visitors. So, if a "future you" was doing a search only using the terms you're using, they'd then be able to find the right question/terms *via* your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of systems for signed integers.

One of them, sign-magnitude, is exactly what you expect: a part that says how big the number is, and a bit that either leaves the number positive or negates it. That makes the sign bit really special, substantially different than the other bits. For example:

```
sign-magnitude representation
0_0000000 = 0
0_0000001 = 1
1_0000001 = -1
1_0000000 = -0
```

This has some uncomfortable side-effects, mainly no longer corresponding to unsigned arithmetic in a useful way (if you add two sign-magnitude integers as if they are unsigned weird things happen, eg -0 + 1 = -1), which has far-reaching consequences: addition/subtraction/equals/multiplication all need special signed versions of them, multiplication and division by powers of two in no way corresponds to bit shifts (except accidentally), since it has no clear correlation to Z/2^k Z it's not immediately clear how it behaves algebraically. Also -0 exists as separate thing from 0, which is weird and causes different kinds of trouble depending on your semantics for it, but never no trouble.

The most common system by far is two's complement, where the sign bit does not mean "times 1 or times -1" but "add 0 or add -2^k". As with one's complement, the sign bit is *largely* a completely normal bit (except with respect to division and right shift). For example:

```
two's complement representation (8bit)
00000000 = 0 (no surprises there)
10000000 = -128
01111111 = 127
11111111 = -1 (= -128 + 127)
etc
```

Now note that 11111111 + 00000001 = 0 in unsigned 8bit arithmetic anyway, and -1+1=0 is clearly desirable (in fact it is the definition of -1). So what it comes down to, at least for addition/subtraction/multiplication/left shift, is plain old unsigned arithmetic - you just print the numbers differently. Of course some operators still need special signed versions. Since it corresponds to unsigned arithmetic so closely, you can reason about additions and multiplications as if you are in Z/2^k Z with total confidence. It does have a slight oddity comparable with the existence of negative zero, namely the existence of a negative number with no positive absolute value.

Comment: Adding -128 explains the "backwards" counting to me, although it still seems odd. But you gave me enough information to continue searching on my own, I didn't know the terms before. Thanks

Comment: @fay ok great. Btw I'd actually call the sign-magnitude "backwards", in the sense that you add one to the representation of a negative number it becomes *more negative* (hence why it needs a special addition that isn't the same as normal addition)

Comment: Also, I assume this is chiefly a matter of performance, so would this explain why division is relatively slower than other arithmetic? I was under the impression it was just more complicated in general because of remainders, but the exception to division in your answer makes me curious.

Comment: @fay division is complicated in general, even unsigned division. But it might be related. Division has annoying properties, that both make it slow and it make it care about signedness, maybe it's not the same properties that cause that I'd have to look into it some more.

Answer (score 2):

The idea to make the value the same and to just put a plus or minus in front is a known idea, called a *signed magnitude* representation or a similar expression. A discussion [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/1-Intro/2-data-repr/signed.html) says the two major problems with signed magnitude representation are that there are two zeros (plus and minus), and that integer arithmetic becomes more complicated in the computer algorithm.

A popular alternative for computers is a *two's complement* representation, which is what you are asking about. This representation makes arithmetic algorithms simpler, but looks weird when you imagine plotting the binary values along a number line, as you are doing. Two's complement also has a single zero, which takes care of the first major problem.

The signed number representations article in Wikipedia has [comparison tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table) illustrating signed magnitude, two's complement, and three other representation systems of values in a decimal number line from -11 to +16 and in a binary value chart from 0000 to 1111.